# Suppress constraint and layout warnings in Xcode 5

Tags: xcode, layout, storyboard, interface-builder, constraints

I'm trying to have custom constraints for objects in my storyboard but I get a bunch of warnings that say

`Misplaced View Frame for "Some object" will be different at run time.`

or

`Ambiguous Layout: Width and horizontal position are ambiguous for "Some object"`

The problems is that if I let Xcode resolve them it will mess up the custom constraints I've set up. The recommended constrains make the layout look bizarre. So how can I suppress these warnings because I'm trying to do something very customized?

Comment: Some information about the constraints you have and the layout you are aiming for would be good. Otherwise, the answer is just "add the right constraints".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys I've solved the problem. I was pretty new to autolayout so it was very frustrating trying to learn it by trial and error.

I solved it by reading this awesome [**autolayout Xcode 5 tutorial**](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50317/beginning-auto-layout-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1) and adding the necessary constraints.

If anyone else is having problems with constraints I can't reccomend the tutorial enough.

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to disable storyboard warnings altogether, go to your project build settings and set "Interface Builder Storyboard Compiler - Options" -> "Show Warnings" to "No."